# Unable to scrape containers from webpages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urlopen

I am trying to practice web-scraping from a e-commerce webpage. I have identified the class name of the container (cell which contains each product) to be `'c3e8SH'`. I then used the following code to scrape for all containers in that webpage. After which, I used `len(containers)` to check the number of containers in the webpage.

However, it returned a 0. Can someone point out what I am doing incorrectly? Thank you very much!

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.lazada.sg/catalog/?spm=a2o42.home.search.1.488d46b5mJGzEu&q=switch%20games&_keyori=ss&from=search_history&sugg=switch%20games_0_1'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

#grabs each product
containers = page_soup.find_all('div', class_='c3e8SH')
len(containers)
```

[image: screenshot of element inspection]

Comment: Are you sure that the class name was 'c3e8SH'? I try solve your problem with regex, but I couldn't find any class with name of 'c3e8SH'.

Comment: @hamedbaziyad i have added a photo, am I referencing the wrong thing?

Comment: Please, determine your section in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

#### (1) Firstly,  param `cookies is needed`.

You will `get the validation page` as below if you only request the link  `without cookies`

https://www.lazada.sg/catalog/?spm=a2o42.home.search.1.488d46b5mJGzEu&q=switch%20games&_keyori=ss&from=search_history&sugg=switch%20games_0_1

[image]

#### (2) secondly, The page you want to scrape is `dynamicly loaded`

> That's why what you see through web browser is different from what you get by codes

for convenience , i'd prefer to use `requests` module.

```py
import requests


my_url = 'https://www.lazada.sg/catalog/?spm=a2o42.home.search.1.488d46b5mJGzEu&q=switch%20games&_keyori=ss&from=search_history&sugg=switch%20games_0_1'


cookies = {
    "Hm_lvt_7cd4710f721b473263eed1f0840391b4":"1548133175,1548135160,1548135844",
    "Hm_lpvt_7cd4710f721b473263eed1f0840391b4":"1548135844",
    "x5sec":"7b22617365727665722d6c617a6164613b32223a223862623264333633343063393330376262313364633537653564393939303732434c50706d754946454e2b4b356f7231764b4c643841453d227d",
}

ret = requests.get(my_url, cookies=cookies)
print("New Super Mario Bros" in ret.text) # True 

# then you can get a json-style shop-items in ret.text
```

shop-items like as:

```
item_json = 

    {
        "@context":"https://schema.org",
        "@type":"ItemList",
        "itemListElement":[
            {
                "offers":{
                    "priceCurrency":"SGD",
                    "@type":"Offer",
                    "price":"72.90",
                    "availability":"https://schema.org/InStock"
                },
                "image":"https://sg-test-11.slatic.net/p/ae0494e8a5eb7412830ac9822984f67a.jpg",
                "@type":"Product",
                "name":"Nintendo Switch New Super Mario Bros U Deluxe",  # item name
                "url":"https://www.lazada.sg/products/nintendo-switch-new-super-mario-bros-u-deluxe-i292338164-s484601143.html?search=1"
            },
            ... 

        ]

    }
```

as json data showed, you can get any item's name, url-link, price, and so on.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this, I copied your code (from the import requests), however, I am returned with a False. Also, where do you get the strings of codes under cookies? Will appreciate very much if you can enlighten me thanks!

Comment: @Daimon you can find it from `request headers` by your web browser

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different parser.
I recommend `lxml`.
So your line where you create the `page_soup` would be:
`page_soup = soup(page_html, 'lxml')`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find `c3e8SH` in your suggested document with `regex`, but I coudn't find such class name. Please, check your document again.